# Customize ng-multiselect-dropdown Component border

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown for multiselect in angular. I want to disable the borders and keep only bottom border of ng-multiselect-dropdown text-box and change the style of arrow mark also.

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown  [placeholder]="'Select Your Item'"
                           [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                           [data]="dropdownList"
                           formControlName="category"
                           (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                           (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                           (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
                           (onDeSelectAll)="onUnSelectAll()">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

I want to use these styles border-left:none, border-right:none,border-top:none to be implemented in textbox.

Comment: Looks like you know what you want, what is the problem? Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite multiselect styles, by creating an overwrite style file or even creating a custom theme.

The component package has a themes folder in node_modules at ng-multiselet-dropdown\themes\ng-multiselect-dropdown.theme.scss

You could us it as guideline.